# Passing arrays into functions

Tags: c, arrays

hi I'm attempting to create a program that accepts a 7 element array as an argument and returns the third through fifth element of that array to a smaller array however i'm currently getting this error

```
assign8p7.c: In function 'main':
assign8p7.c:18:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'copysect' makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [enabled by default]
assign8p7.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

from what i can tell the warning has a problem with me passing it an array in the arguments does anyone know how i might fix this? also any other advice for my code is welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int *copysect(int ar[],int start,int end)
{
int i;
static int retar[3];
for(i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    retar[i+start]=ar[i+start];
}
return retar;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int arry[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int miniarry[3];
miniarry[0] = *copysect(arry[0],3,5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit your title to be more informative please..

Comment: @MarounMaroun, you have the ability do it yourself, you know :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, but I want him to know that he should do it (for the future) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are calling the function `copysect` with the first element in the array, not the pointer to the array. The correct call is:

   ```
   copysect(arry,3,5);
   ```
2. You could calculate the difference of the array dynamically. Now the caller of copysect function has to know that the difference between start and end is 2.

   ```
   int retar[end - start + 1]
   ```
3. The assignment in the for loop is wrong. You are dereferencing a value that is out of scope of retar array

   ```
   retar[i]=ar[i+start];
   ```
4. When calling the `copysect` function, you are assigning only the first element in the `miniarry` by dereferencing the array that the function returns, instead of the whole array.
5. It's not the best idea to have a static array in a function (that would be problematic if you called the function more than once, etc). Instead, you could declare the smaller array elswhere and pass it as a parameter to the function.

   ```
   void copysect(int ar[], int retar[], int start,int end, )
   ```

Comment: thank you for the information i'll be sure to use it if i could ask you one more quick question i made the changes you suggested in your answer and i'm getting an error on line 17 of my code that states miniarry is an incompatible type when assigning to type 'int[3]' from int now i'm assuming this is because my function returns an int and not an array however when i remove the int declaration my program crashes any thoughts as to why this may be?

Answer (score 5):

```
int *copysect(int ar[],int start,int end)
```

Okay, `copysect` takes as its first parameter an array of integers.

```
miniarry[0] = *copysect(arry[0],3,5);
```

Oops, you passed it a single integer instead of an array.

Comment: Oops! If only something could have told him that.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Sadly, all the compiler said was `assign8p7.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'` which is no help at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, there should be some sarcasm sign on SO. Took me a minute to figure out what your last comment meant :)